# Error Message R CRAN UPLOAD

Tags: r, package, cran

Uploading my package on **CRAN** I got the following error message on the check results page.
See also [CHECK PAGE](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_imputeTS.html)

> Check: whether package can be installed 
>   Result: WARN
>
> Found the following significant warnings:
>
> Warning: S3 methods '[.fun_list', '[.grouped_df', 'all.equal.tbl_df', 'anti_join.data.frame', 'anti_join.tbl_df', 'arrange.data.frame', 'arrange.default', 'arrange.grouped_df', 'arrange.tbl_df', 'arrange_.data.frame', 'arrange_.tbl_df', 'as.data.frame.grouped_df', 'as.data.frame.rowwise_df', 'as.data.frame.tbl_cube', 'as.data.frame.tbl_df', 'as.table.tbl_cube', 'as.tbl.data.frame', 'as.tbl.tbl', 'as.tbl_cube.array', 'as.tbl_cube.data.frame', 'as.tbl_cube.matrix', 'as.tbl_cube.table', 'as_data_frame.grouped_df', 'as_data_frame.tbl_cube', 'auto_copy.tbl_cube', 'auto_copy.tbl_df', 'cbind.grouped_df', 'collapse.data.frame', 'collect.data.frame', 'common_by.NULL', 'common_by.character', 'common_by.default', 'common_by.list', 'compute.data.frame', 'copy_to.DBIConnection', 'copy_to.src_local', 'default_missing.data.frame', 'default_missing.default', 'dim.tbl_cube', 'distinct.data.frame', 'distinct.default', 'distinct.grouped_df', 'distinct.tbl_df', 'distinct_.data.frame', 'distinct_.grouped_df', 'dist [... truncated]
>
> Flavor: r-oldrel-windows-ix86+x86_64

Seems to be only relevant for old release windows-ix86+x86_64. 
I actually have no clue what this message might mean or how to fix this. Does somebody know more about this problem?

Comment: Those error all look related to dplyr. Does your package use dplyr? What does your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE file look like? Did you require a particular R version?

Comment: All these function are dplyr related, it's odd they are parsed here. How do you specified your dependencies ?

Comment: Judging from [your current `NAMESPACE`](https://github.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/blob/master/NAMESPACE), it does not appear that you are treating these functions differently. (For the crowd) Was there a change in R install-checks between 3.4.4 ("oldrel") and 3.5.1 ("release")?

Comment: Strange....I do not use dplyr at all in the whole package. But I am using magrittr (for pipe operator). Good hint this might be the cause. The error message actually appeared with my newest updated that included the magrittr import.

Comment: Ok I know now the problem probably comes along with my magrittr usage. You already brought me forward. Thx for this.  Still I don't get why exactly this message appears and why only with oldrel.

Comment: @MrFlick I have a Depends: R (≥ 3.0.1) - guess this can't be the reason, this is well below  3.4.4 ("oldrel") and 3.5.1 ("release") which are checked

Comment: I have the same problem. Am using `dplyr` package. Just noticed I had same problem with my last CRAN submission but went through ok. Any updates on a fix?

Comment: Have the same problem with [model4you](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/model4you/). I'd be interested to hear what the problem is. I don't even use `dplyr`.

Comment: According to Uwe Ligges, the problem should resolve itself (it's a *race condition*) and can be ignored (at least in my case).

Comment: Thx Heidi. Also an update from me:  the problem just disappeared without me doing anything. So if you encounter the exact same problem - just waiting seems to be the solution.